# Is there a way to filter a JSON object using jq to only include those with a key matching a value from a known list?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON array, and another text file that contains a list of values.

```json
[
    {
      "key": "foo",
      "detail": "bar"
    },
    ...
]
```

I need to filter the array elements to only those that have a "key" value that is found in the list of values.

The list of values is a text file containing a single item per-line.

```
foo
baz
```

Is this possible to do using `jq`?

Comment: Is the array stored in a file? How does the list of values look?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible. Your question as it stands may not be as clear to others as it is to you.

Comment: Should it matter if the array is in a file? It's not really important if it's in a file or in a pipe, is it?

Comment: It matters because jq only reads from one handle. And the format of the data (whether pipe or stream) was also a relevant missing detail. But it turns out I guessed correctly and my answer has a solution for you. I'm not sure why you didn't accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```sh
jq --rawfile to_keep_file to_keep.txt '
   ( [ $to_keep_file | match(".+"; "g").string | { (.): true } ] | add ) as $to_keep_lkup |
   map(select($to_keep_lkup[.key]))
' to_filter.json
```

or

```sh
(
   jq -sR . to_keep.txt
   cat to_filter.json
) | jq -n '
   ( [ input | match(".+"; "g").string | { (.): true } ] | add ) as $to_keep_lkup |
   inputs | map(select($to_keep_lkup[.key]))
'
```

The former requires jq v1.6, the first version to provide `--rawfile`.

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/88XwbPkPe4)